# Adjust CGPath size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

**Introduction**

I have a `CGPath` I create from a `SVG` file using `PocketSVG` API. It all works fine.

**The Problem**

The problem is that the shape stretches for some reason, please take a look on this picture (the blue color is just to make is more visible to you, please ignore it, it should be `ClearColor`):

[image: Image 1]
**The Target**

What do I want to achieve? I want to achieve a shape that goes all over the screen's width (I don't care about the height, it should modify itself according to the width), and sticks to the bottom of the screen, please take a look on this picture as well (please ignore the circular button):

[image: Image 2]

**The Code**

The important part ;)

I have a subclass of `UIView` that draws this shape from the `SVG` file, it called `CategoriesBarView`. Then, on my `MainViewController` (a subclass of `UIViewController`) I'm creating an object of `CategoriesBarView` and setting it programmatically as a subview.

*`CategoriesBarView`:*

```
class CategoriesBarView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let myPath = PocketSVG.pathFromSVGFileNamed("CategoriesBar").takeUnretainedValue()

        var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.frame.size.width / 750.0, self.frame.size.height / 1334.0)
        let transformedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &transform)

        let myShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        myShapeLayer.path = transformedPath

        let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        effectView.frame.size = self.frame.size
        effectView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        effectView.layer.mask = myShapeLayer

        self.addSubview(effectView)

    }
}
```

*`MainViewController`:*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let testHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height / 6 // 1/6 of the screen’s height, that is the height in the target picture approximately, doesn’t it?

    let categoriesBarView = CategoriesBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - testHeight , width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: testHeight))
        categoriesBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // AS I said, it should be ClearColor
    self.view.addSubview(categoriesBarView)
}
```

Does anyone of you know what is the problem here and why the shape is stretching like that? I'll really appreciate if someone could help me here.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Have you tried to scale you path according to screen resolution?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara What do you mean? How can I do that? What should I change in my code? Thank you!

Comment: Lets say you draw a path in 100x100 and you want it too look same in 320x100 then multiply your path's x points with 3.2 as its new area is 3.2 time more than your actual path. Simple scaling of your path.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I don't really understand, how does it relevant for the stretched path, can you please add a code example to help me understand better? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider following code which draws a Square of 100x100 dimension. What i have done here is taken 100x100 as a base dimension(Because its easy to calculate respective ratio or scale dimension), as you can see i have defined `scaleWidth` and `scaleHeight` variable which represents your current scale for path. Scale is `1.0` at the moment which means it draws a square of 100x100, if you change it to `0.5` and `0.75` respectively it will draw a rectangle of 50X75 pixels. Refer Images which clearly depicts difference between scale width and height as `1.0` and `0.5` and `0.75` respectively.

```
CGFloat scaleWidth = 0.50f;
CGFloat scaleHeight = 0.75f;

//// Square Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierSquarePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// ***Starting point of path ***
[bezierSquarePath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(1, 1)];

// *** move to x and y position to draw lines, calculate respective x & y position using scaleWidth & scaleHeight ***
[bezierSquarePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(100*scaleWidth, 1)];
[bezierSquarePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(100*scaleWidth, 100*scaleHeight)];
[bezierSquarePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(1, 100*scaleHeight)];

// *** end your path ***
[bezierSquarePath closePath];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierSquarePath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierSquarePath stroke];
```

Image 1 : Represents 100x100 square using scaleWidth = 1.0 and scaleHeight = 1.0
[image: Represents 100x100 square using scaleWidth = 1.0 and scaleHeight = 1.0]

Image 2 : Represents 50x75 square using scaleWidth = 0.50 and scaleHeight = 0.75
[image: Represents 100x100 square using scaleWidth = 0.50 and scaleHeight = 0.75]

> Note: In given images all the drawing is done in `UIView`'s `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method as only `UIView` is capable to draw. I have placed a `UIView` which is highlighted with GrayColor in images.

I believe it gives you a perspective about scaling a path to solve your problem as you can not use the same code but you can generate one using it.

**Helpful Tool** : If you are not expert in Graphics coding you can recommend to use [PaintCode software](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) which generates Objective-C code with UI. Thought there might be other softwares you can opt for.

Happy coding :)